# Problem with Floats! (in PHP)

Tags: php, floating-point

What's wrong with php floats?

```
$v = 5.2 * 3;

if($v==15.6) {
    echo 'Everything is fine =)';
} else {
    echo 'Okay something is wrong :S';
    var_dump($v); // float 15.6
}
```

Check this out too:

```
$v = 5.2 * 3;

if($v>15.6 AND $v<15.60000000001) {
    echo 'We are doomed :S';
    var_dump($v); // float 15.6
} else {
    echo 'Everything is fine =)';
}
```

I guess it has something to do with the internal representation or some obscure low level stuff? If that's the case, how do I get around this issue?
Anything else I should know before using this to calculate real money transactions?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Real vs. Floating Point vs. Money](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/273371/real-vs-floating-point-vs-money)

Comment: *(reference)* http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.bccomp.php

Comment: This should be helpful: http://docs.sun.com/source/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I am sure this is a duplicate, so I'm making this a CW

```
$v = 5.2 * 3;
if (bccomp($v, 15.6) === 0) {
    echo 'Everything is fine =)';
} else {
    echo 'Okay something is wrong :S';
    var_dump($v); // float 15.6
}
```

will give 'Everything is fine =)'

Answer (score 4):

It has to do with the internal representation indeed :). Never compare float values. I think there will exists php classes/modules that work around this problem, but you can also store your money values as integers and multiply them by `100`. Before display you can divide them again :)

Answer (score 2):

This has to do with floats in general and is not limited to PHP.

When using floats you should check for intervals with a specific precision, just as you did in your last example:

```
if(abs($v - 15.6) < 0.0001)
{
    // Yey :)
}
```

You can run into a lot of problems when using exact values.

Answer (score 2):

the value you are getting is 15.600000000000001 and it is diferent to 15.6, this topic has been widely discussed, you can take a look to this threads:

- [Imprecise numbers with microtime and floating point addition in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1031170/imprecise-numbers-with-microtime-and-floating-point-addition-in-php)
- [Compare floats in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3148937/compare-floats-in-php)

HTH, Regards

Answer (score 2):

The [PHP page on floats](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php) has a warning against comparing for equality and also links to [this page](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.bc.php) which links to [`bccomp`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.bccomp.php).

Answer (score 2):

If you really need to compare floats check for being in bounds of an allowed deviation instead of an exact match, like

```
$DEVIATION = 0.0001;
if(abs($v-15.6)<$DEVIATION) ...
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$v = 5.2 * 3;

if((string)$v == "15.6") {
    print "yes";
}
```

It's always good to check PHP website as most developers have come across problems before [PHP.net Floating Point Number](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php#100289) this comment shows a function for comparing floats.

```
<?php 
    function IsFloatEqual($x,$y,$precision=0.0000001) 
    { 
        return ($x+$precision >= $y) && ($x-$precision <= $y); 
    } 
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just a minor addition for anywone looking:

the BC* functions are the *only* true way to work with floats in PHP!