# PHP : convert String to Float when possible

Tags: php, type-conversion

In PHP, I need to write a function that takes a string and returns its conversion to a float whenever possible, otherwise just returns the input string.

I thought this function would work. Obviously the comparison is wrong, but I don't understand why.

```
function toNumber ($input) {
    $num = floatval($input); // Returns O for a string
    if ($num == $input) { // Not the right comparison?
        return $num;
    } else {
        return $input;
    }
}

echo(gettype(toNumber("1"))); // double
echo(gettype(toNumber("3.14159"))); // double
echo(gettype(toNumber("Coco"))); // double (expected: string)
```

Comment: Check this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4276516/problem-with-floats-in-php

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
function toNumber($input) {
    return is_numeric($input) ? (float)$input : $input;
}
```

Comment: is_numeric? Well.. hem... OK.

Comment: Makes sense if you think about it, no? ;-3

Comment: That's the trouble with PHP. Too many built-in functions with imprectidable names (well, not this one)!

Comment: Mmm, fair enough. It's worth perusing the list of basic functions once or twice though, like all string functions and all number functions. There's aren't *that* many... :)

Answer (score 1):

try `if($num){return $num;}else{return $input}`, this will work fine, it will only jump to else statement part, when $num = 0

Answer (score 0):

Well the fastest thing would be checking if $num == 0 rather than $num == $input, if I understand this correctly.