# Pearson Correlation returns 0 on exact matchs

Tags: php, pearson-correlation

I am using this PHP routine to calc Pearson Correlation:

```
function correlation ($x,$y) {
    $length = count($x);
    $mean1 = array_sum($x)/$length;
    $mean2 = array_sum($y)/$length;
    $a = $b = 0;
    $a2 = $b2 = 0;
    $axb = 0;
    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
        $a = $x[$i]-$mean1;
        $b = $y[$i]-$mean2;
        $axb +=$a*$b;
        $a2 += pow($a,2);
        $b2 += pow($b,2);
    }
    if ($sqrt = sqrt($a2*$b2))
        return $axb/$sqrt;
    return 0;
}
```

When I test it for several conditions it returns 0 on exact matchs:

```
echo correlation([0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0]); // Returns 0!!
echo correlation([0,0,0,0,0],[1,1,1,1,1]); // Returns 0!!
echo correlation([1,1,1,1,1],[1,1,1,1,1]); // Returns 0!!
echo correlation([0,0,0,0,0],[9,9,9,9,9]); // Returns 0!!
echo correlation([0,0,0,0,0],[0,1,2,3,4]); // Returns 0 OK
echo correlation([9,9,9,9,9],[0,1,2,3,4]); // Returns 0 OK
echo correlation([0,1,2,3,4],[0,1,2,3,4]); // Returns 1 OK
```

Why? and How to accomplish that? Thank you!

---

**For info:**

> A Pearson correlation is a number between -1 and 1 that indicates the
>   extent to which two variables are linearly related. The Pearson
>   correlation is also known as the “product moment correlation
>   coefficient” (PMCC) or simply “correlation”.

Comment: " How to accomplish that?"...how to accomplish what? You didn't mention what the expected result was

Comment: I already forgot all the stats I learnt at university but you get zero because that's your default return value to avoid division by zero. When you basically have a single dot in your scatter plot it doesn't make sense to calculate correlation.

Comment: @ADyson 00000 and 00000 are equal and has full correlation, so why it returns 0 instead of 1, and how to make it return 1?

Comment: 1 means your values form a perfect line and Y grows when X grows. Two equal values can't form a line (or they can form infinite lines in any direction, however you want to consider). Wikipedia has a [nice chart](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson_correlation_coefficient#/media/File:Correlation_coefficient.png). To get 1 just replace `return 0;` with `return 1;`—but I doubt it's mathematically correct. I think a better result would be `null`.

Answer (score 2):

### Approach 1 (doing at your own):

Using PHP to statistics is a hard path.

First of all, as you're using a weak typed language (you don't need to specify the types on variables), the language can interpret as `int` so,  you need to set all of your variables on type `float` and execute again to run this. You can have some problems with float in PHP, see here why I talking this: https://3v4l.org/1FU9J

But if you don't mind about high precision, you can modify your precision you can set your `round()` function or you can set `ini_set('precision', 3);` to get the precision on your data.

Another thing. If you need precision, you need to  use `bc` extension because floating point in PHP is a problem and can affect your results.

Look more about `bc math` extension here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.bc.php or try to use another language.

Some references about the floating point:

- https://www.leaseweb.com/labs/2013/06/the-php-floating-point-precision-is-wrong-by-default/
- [Problem with Floats! (in PHP)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4276516/problem-with-floats-in-php)

---

### Approach 2 (using language functions):

And, PHP have some functions to help in this. So, if this isn't a homework to learn or something like this, you can try this: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stats-stat-correlation.php

Comment: The problem with `int` and `float` actually happens with strongly typed languages as C, where `10/3` renders `3`. In loosely typed languages as PHP you automagically get the [appropriate conversions](https://3v4l.org/VMtkb).

Comment: Also, floating point maths precision is a problem when you want 30 decimals or you have a 500-digit integer.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález Your consideration about `C` language is right. But, as the following example (https://3v4l.org/1FU9J) we can see that something is not exactly right in PHP.