# How to subtract microtime and display date with milliseconds in php?

Tags: php, microtime

How to subtract microtime and display date with milliseconds in php ?

For example:  I have set end date and time

```
$endtime = 2012-02-21 10:29:59;
```

then I have current date or start date with converted from microtime

```
$starttime = 2012-02-21 10:27:59.452;

function getTimestamp()
{
        $microtime = floatval(substr((string)microtime(), 1, 8));
        $rounded = round($microtime, 3);
        return date("Y-m-d H:i:s") . substr((string)$rounded, 1, strlen($rounded));
}

echo getTimestamp(); //sample output 2012-02-21 10:27:59.452
```

Now I want to subtract:
$finaldate = $endtime - $starttime;

I want my output to be like this: **00:00:02.452**

Answer (score 31):

You need to use `microtime` for the start/end values, and only format it for display at the end.

```
// Get the start time in microseconds, as a float value
$starttime = microtime(true);

/************/
/* Do stuff */
/************/

// Get the difference between start and end in microseconds, as a float value
$diff = microtime(true) - $starttime;

// Break the difference into seconds and microseconds
$sec = intval($diff);
$micro = $diff - $sec;

// Format the result as you want it
// $final will contain something like "00:00:02.452"
$final = strftime('%T', mktime(0, 0, $sec)) . str_replace('0.', '.', sprintf('%.3f', $micro));
```

*Note: this is returning float values from `microtime` and using float arithmetic to simplify the math, so your numbers may be extremely slightly off due to the float rounding problem, but you are rounding the result to 3 digits in the end anyway, and minor fluctuations in processor timing are greater than floating point errors anyway, so this is not problem for you on multiple levels.*

Comment: I will point out that actually the imprecision in microtime is a display issue only. microtime(true) actually returns a more precise number than is displayed. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1031170/imprecise-numbers-with-microtime-and-floating-point-addition-in-php

Answer (score 3):

Well phpmyadmin uses this a code like this to calculate the time that a query took. It's similar to your requirements:

```
//time before
list($usec, $sec) = explode(' ',microtime($starttime));
$querytime_before = ((float)$usec + (float)$sec);
/* your code */

//time after
list($usec, $sec) = explode(' ',microtime($endtime));
$querytime_after = ((float)$usec + (float)$sec);
$querytime = $querytime_after - $querytime_before;
```

I think this should work for you. You just have to figure your output format