# Date with this format "1976-03-06T23:59:59.999Z"

Tags: php, date

How can I get a date in PHP with this format?

```
1976-03-06T23:59:59.999Z
```

I want the current date + 10 hours in that format. I have tried this:

```
date("Y-m-d",strtotime("+10 hours"));
```

but I fail to see how to get that format.

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9371457/how-to-subtract-microtime-and-display-date-with-miliseconds-in-php

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP date format converting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2332740/php-date-format-converting)

Answer (score 2):

To get precisely what you are looking for you will need to do the following:

Set the PHP timezone to ensure that regardless of your server or PHP timezone, the time output will be in correct zone (in your case 'Z').

```
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
```

Then compute the time you need (current time plus 10 hours);

```
$timestamp = time() + (10 * 60 * 60); // now + 10 hours * 60 minutes * 60 seconds
```

Then convert to a formatted date.

If you are not concerned about the seconds and milliseconds, then use PHP's inbuilt function for ISO 8601 dates.

```
echo date('c', $timestamp); // Will output 1976-03-06T23:59Z
```

else you will need to determine the current microseconds and assemble the date string manually.

```
// Get current timestamp and milliseconds 
list($microsec, $timestamp) = explode(" ", microtime()); 

// reduce microtime to 3 dp
$microsec = substr($microsec,0,3); 

// Add 10 hours (36,000 seconds) to the timestamp
$timestamp = (int)$timestamp + (10 * 60 * 60); 

// Construct and echo the date string
echo date('Y-m-d', $timestamp) . 'T' . date('H:i:s', $timestamp) . '.' . $microsec . 'Z';
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add `10 * 60 * 60` seconds to the current `time`.

```
date('c', time() + 10 * 60 * 60);
```

Comment: +10 hours from the topic starter is safer to use. Your function can cause errors if you use daylight savings timezones on the server.

Comment: The timezone stated above is 'Z' so why not normalise the server time by setting `date_default_timezone_set('UTC');`

Comment: @Clarence The `time` function works in UTC.

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty close to what you're looking for.

```
date('c')
// prints 2013-01-03T18:39:07-05:00
```

As others have said, check the documentation to make something more customized.